# Moment js undefined after r.js building

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, momentjs, backgrid

Did anyone successfully loaded moment.js in a r.js build (with almond) ?

I am using backgrid and backgridMomentCell: everything's works perfectly before I build my main.min.js file. After build time moment is not defined and thus can't be found by backgridMomentCell extension.

I've tried several option (even shim) without success.

If somedoby has a require.config that work can he/she shares it ?

EDIT (sorry for not answering any sooner, launch time kept me away from SO):

In the build file BackGridMomentCell keep throwing "moment is not defined" errors.

My code as requested in the comment

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        backbone: 'vendor/backbone-1.1.0',
        backbonePageable: 'vendor/backbone-pageable-1.4.1',
        backgrid: 'vendor/backgrid/js/backgrid-0.2.6',
        backgridPaginator: 'vendor/backgrid/js/extensions/paginator/backgrid-paginator',
        backgridMomentCell: 'vendor/backgrid/js/extensions/moment-cell/backgrid-moment-cell',
        bootstrap: 'vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-3.0.1',
        bootstrapDatepicker: 'vendor/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker-fda46bb',
        codemirror: 'vendor/codemirror/js/codemirror-3.20',
        codemirrorMarkdown: 'vendor/codemirror/mode/markdown/markdown',
        jsDiff: 'vendor/diff-1.0.7',
        fullCalendar: 'vendor/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-1.6.4',
        fullCalendarJqueryUiCustom: 'vendor/fullcalendar/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min',
        jquery: 'vendor/jquery-1.10.2',
        marked: 'vendor/marked-0.2.10',
        select2: 'vendor/select2/select2-3.4.5',
        speakingurl: 'vendor/speakingurl-0.4.0',
        underscore: 'vendor/underscore-1.5.2',
        moment: 'vendor/moment.with.langs'

    },
    shim: {
        backbone: {
            deps: ['jquery', 'underscore'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        },
        backgrid: {
            deps: ['jquery', 'backbone', 'underscore'],
            exports: 'Backgrid'
        },
        backgridPaginator: {
            deps: ['backgrid']
        },
        backgridMomentCell: {
            deps: ['backgrid','moment']
        },
        bootstrap: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        bootstrapDatepicker: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        codemirror: {
            exports: 'CodeMirror'
        },
        codemirrorMarkdown: {
            deps: ['codemirror'],
            exports: 'codemirrorMarkdown'
        },
        fullCalendar: {
            deps: ['jquery', 'fullCalendarJqueryUiCustom']
        },
        fullCalendarJqueryUiCustom: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        select2: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        underscore: {
            exports: '_'
        }
    }
});
```

The head of my module

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'fullCalendar',
    'underscore',
    'backgrid',
    'backgridPaginator',
    'moment',
    'backgridMomentCell',
    'backbone',
    'collections/ItemPaginatedCollection',
    'utils/BackgridCustomUriCell'
], function ($, _fullCalendar, _, Backgrid, _backgridPaginator, moment, MomentCell,Backbone, ItemPaginatedCollection, BackgridCustomUriCell) {
```

```
"use strict";
```

....

**EDIT 3 :**

Loading moment.js before my compiled main.js works but is not optimal IMHO.

Comment: am using moment.js with twitter bootstrap , working fine with out isssue , can you please share your code and the piece of work you need to do

Answer (score 1):

The easiest two methods I have found:

1) Wrap backgrid-moment-cell.js in the [CommonJS wrapper code](http://requirejs.org/docs/commonjs.html#manualconversion) specified in the RequireJS API.  You can do this dynamically during the build process using the conversion tool mentioned in the API.

2) Require moment-cell inline and set findNestedDependencies to false in your build.js.

The issue is that the moment-cell code passes in `this` to itself when it is initialized, and looks for either "exports.moment" or "this.moment."

On a related note, including moment in the shim for moment-cell is unnecessary, and technically you should include underscore.  [From the API](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim):

> Only use other "shim" modules as dependencies for shimmed scripts, or
>   AMD libraries that have no dependencies and call define() after they
>   also create a global (like jQuery or lodash). Otherwise, if you use an
>   AMD module as a dependency for a shim config module, after a build,
>   that AMD module may not be evaluated until after the shimmed code in
>   the build executes, and an error will occur. The ultimate fix is to
>   upgrade all the shimmed code to have optional AMD define() calls.

Moment is actually an AMD module.

Comment: Didn't see your detailed comment until now. Thanks. As a note seems moment.js has been fixed for this (didn't check though) https://github.com/wyuenho/backgrid-moment-cell/issues/5

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your problem is that you didn't specify `findNestedDependencies` true in your build file.

Take a look at this commit (from my [book on RquireJS and Backbone.Marionette](https://leanpub.com/structuring-backbone-with-requirejs-and-marionette)): https://github.com/davidsulc/structuring-backbone-with-requirejs-and-marionette/commit/85d3d3dd40d0cebd858224c3903a12d6998d668d

Comment: I tried without success. (Bought your book month ago, great work, really useful)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's to do with moment's global object being deprecated.

`2.4.0 - Deprecate globally exported moment, will be removed in next major`

https://github.com/moment/moment

Moment needs to be defined in the specific module now.

Comment: I did defined it in the module but same problem : works like a charm when using all files separately and throwing error when building one main file